# MongoDB MonkAPI setting a variable based on find result that is available outside the db request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I'm trying to set a variable based on the result of a find through Monk API on MongoDB in a Node JS application (it's my first time of using MongoDB).

This is an example of the code I have;

```
var variableIWantToSet;
var collection = req.db.get('myCollection');
collection.find( { foo: 'bar' },{
  fields : { myTargetField: 1, _id: 0},
  limit : 1,
  sort : {$natural : -1}
}
, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    variableIWantToSet = doc[0].myTargetField;
});
console.log(variableIWantToSet);
```

If I `console.log(doc[0].myTargetField)` within the function I get the right value, but the `console.log(variableIWantToSet)` returns `undefined`.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the console.log is outside the callback. so that it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the console.log is outside the callback. so that it's `undefined`. Put it in the callback.

```
var collection = req.db.get('myCollection');
collection.find( { foo: 'bar' },{
  fields : { myTargetField: 1, _id: 0},
  limit : 1,
  sort : {$natural : -1}
}
, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    var variableIWantToSet = doc[0].myTargetField;
    console.log(variableIWantToSet);
});
```

for making it easier to understand :

```
 //The callback function will be call after the mongodb response right value.
var callback = function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    variableIWantToSet = doc[0].myTargetField;
    console.log(variableIWantToSet); // return doc[0].myTargetField;
}; 

var variableIWantToSet;

var collection = req.db.get('myCollection');
collection.find( { foo: 'bar' },{
  fields : { myTargetField: 1, _id: 0},
  limit : 1,
  sort : {$natural : -1}
}
, callback);
 console.log(variableIWantToSet); // return undefined;
```

if you don't understand about `callback`, google it, it's the basic of asynchronous programming, which makes javascript different.

Comment: That's great - very understandable answer and tells me what I needed. Am getting used to callbacks - have done most of my programming in Ruby, so a bit of a change of approach.